# getstatusoutput in python returning incorrect result

Tags: python, macos

I am writing a method to open a path in the explorer window in Mac. So, I am using getstatusoutput method of commands module in python. I have the following piece of code :

```
Path = "file:///" + USERHOME
filePath = os.path.join(Path, filePath)

ret, out = commands.getstatusoutput('open "%s"' % filePath)
```

This method is working for most of the files/folders except one named as "old,;'{}&". In this case, it is working if I don't put "file:///" before the actual Path as mentioned above. I did not understand why this is happening. Can anyone point out what am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on version 2.7+ don't use the commands module. It's deprecated and replaced by the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

Secondly don't use the file:/// prefix. Use the -R flag to tell open to reveal it in Finder. From the open man-page:

> -R  Reveals the file(s) in the Finder instead of opening them.

Example:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["open", "-R", "/path/to/myfile/old,;'{}&"])
```

Comment: But actually I need to open the file anyhow from my application whenever user clicks on the link to the file. So, I had used getstatusoutput method. I checked with subprocess.call() method as you mentioned But, still faced the issue to open the file. So, is this the problem because of ';' in the file name ?

Comment: I added an example to my answer. When I execute this in an ipython-shell, Finder opens up, and the file is selected. Otherwise you have to provide more details about exactly what you want to happen.